# Pigeonhole principle, choosing 1-8 numbers out of 27

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

prove that for every 8 choosen numbers from 10 to 36 you can always make equalities.
number can be used once.

examples.

let say that the choosen numbers are

10, 11, 12, 15, 18, 25, 32, 36

you can write

11+25=36 or 10+12+18=15+25.

i tried to prove for summation for every 2 numbers
$$\binom{8}{2}=28 $$

but there are 51 different summation of 2 differend numbers 
Lets say that the nombers are
a b c d e f g h
2 out of 8 is valid because the subsets (ab) and (ac) cannot be equal so they cannot be compared 
But 3 of 8 can be (abc) and (ade) and they can be equal so it is not valid
So i can use only use 2 out of 8 
Baybe i am in the wrong direction.

that's the closest i got

Comment: You have an example with a sum of three numbers. So why do you restrict your counting to two-element subsets?

Comment: thanks for looking, i dont know other way

Comment: Hint: What is the largest possible sum of a non-empty subset? What is the smallest possible sum of a non-empty subset? How many non-empty subsets are there? What can you do, if two non-empty subsets with equal sums share some numbers?

Comment: The Smallest is 10

Comment: You had 8 numbers, no? (the hint is that you worry about repetitions only in the end). And check your arithmetic - seven numbers, all $\ge30$, sum up to at least $7\cdot30=210$ :-). The smallest possible sum is correct.

Comment: Yes its 231 so there are 231-10+1=222 different summations

Comment: So now i need to do $$\binom{8}{1}=8 $$+$$\binom{8}{2}=28 $$+$$\binom{8}{3}=56 $$+$$\binom{8}{4}=70 $$+$$\binom{8}{5}=56 $$+$$\binom{8}{6}=28 $$+$$\binom{8}{7}=8 $$=253

Comment: How did seven even integers sum up to an odd number? And would it not be easier to just use the formula for the number of subsets of a set of 8 elements?

Comment: 254***, which furmula is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S\subset\{10,11,12,\ldots,36\}$ be an arbitray subset of eight integers. The set $S$ itself has $2^8=256$ subsets. Of these $255$ are non-empty. For any subset $U\subset S$, $U\neq\emptyset$, let's denote by $\Sigma(U)$ the sum of elements of $U$. The smallest possible value of $\Sigma(U)$ is clearly
$$
\Sigma(\{10\})=10,
$$
and the largest possible value of $\Sigma(U)$ is
$$
\Sigma(\{36,35,34,\ldots,29\})=4\cdot65=260.
$$
These cannot occur for subsets of the same set $S$, but we don't need to worry about that. No matter what the set $S$ is, the $255$ numbers $\Sigma(U),U\subseteq S, U\neq\emptyset$, are all integers in the range $[10,260]$. That range has $251$ integers, so by the pigeonhole principle there exists two distinct subsets $U_1,U_2\subseteq S$ with the property that
$$
\Sigma(U_1)=\Sigma(U_2).
$$
Getting warmer, but let's not forget that a single element of $S$ can only be used once. In other words, the two sets $U_1,U_2$ should be disjoint. But this does not really form an obstacle for us. For if $V=U_1\cap U_2$ is non-empty, then, denoting $U_1'=U_1\setminus V$ and $U_2'=U_2\setminus V$, we see that
$$\Sigma(U_i)=\Sigma(U_i')+\Sigma(V)$$ for $i=1,2$.
Therefore
$$
\Sigma(U_1')=\Sigma(U_1)-\Sigma(V)=\Sigma(U_2)-\Sigma(V)=\Sigma(U_2').
$$
Thus the disjoint subsets $U_1'$ and $U_2'$ have equal set sums. Because obviously neither of $U_1,U_2$ can be a subset of the other, both $U_1'$ and $U_2'$ are non-empty.

Comment: Perhaps, a bit overkill in detail and formalism. I judged that to be the best in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there is a problem

Comment: How u_1 and u_2 are both partial to any choosen 8 numbers

Comment: I don't understand the question? Both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subsets of $S$. And $S$ is that set of 8 chosen numbers?

Comment: Got it, thank you, you have no idea how helpful is this. I just had to do one step forther .